# When you set Checked property in a RadioBox, can you suppress the CheckChanged event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm new to C# and Windows Form but if I have a radiobutton and I call radiobutton1.Checked=true, is there a way for it to not fire the CheckedChange event? I want to distinguish between the user clicking on the radiobutton and me setting the radiobutton programmatically. Is this possible?

Comment: This sounds like a design issue to me.  What behavior are you trying to define?

Comment: Yes you can probably design around it but I'm used to controls not sending events if SetValue is called. wxWidgets works like this and makes life easier. Ok, looks like the answer is no; event is fired and can't be suppressed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Stop trying to defeat the design of the `CheckedChanged` event.  It's specifically supposed to include programmatic changes.

If you want user-triggered changes and not programmatic changes, use the [`Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) event instead.  (You may be thinking that you don't want to restrict yourself to mouse clicks, don't worry, there's a `MouseClick` event for that, `Click` includes keyboard changes as well.)

Comment: This does not fire for a `RadioButton` when it goes from a checked to an unchecked state.

Comment: @Ani: genomess said he wanted an event to fire only when the user clicks the button.  I'm pretty sure that no radio button ever becomes unchecked by the user clicking on it.

Comment: This is a fairly common thing to want to distinguish between user and programmatic events, or more specifically, to only want to to be notified about user events. True, there may be cases where you don't care, but it really simplifies things if you can tell them apart. That said, your suggestion of listening for Click events rather than CheckChange events is a good one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a straightforward method of using the event when you feel like it.

```
private bool SuppressRadioButton1Event { get; set; }

private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.SuppressRadioButton1Event)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not suppressed!");
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SetRadioButton1(false);
}

private void SetRadioButton1(bool checkedOn)
{
    this.SuppressRadioButton1Event = true;
    radioButton1.Checked = checkedOn;
    this.SuppressRadioButton1Event = false;
}
```

Comment: +1 I have to admit this way of `flagging` is better than mine :)

Answer (score 3):

A very easy way:

```
public void radio_OnCheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RadioButton r = sender as RadioButton;
   bool isUserChange = r.Tag.Equals(1);
   if (isUserChange) blabla
   else blabla
   r.Tag = null;       
}

public void MyMethod()
{
   radio1.Tag = 1;
   radio.Checked = true;
}
```

You can use any kind of `flag` which users can't do by their clicking.But you can do via your code.

Comment: Setting the tag to another flag instead of null will avoid the null use exception.

Answer (score 1):

Why should your code care who checked the radiobutton?

EDIT: There are ways around this (subclass, flag), but *don't*. The only "legit" reason I can think of for wanting this is to prevent some side-effect from happening when the value is initially (programatically) displayed, and even that is suspect. Rethink the side-effect, does it really belong on the change-event, or the commit?

More info one why/what would help. On the surface, this looks like a design error.

Comment: I think he wants to do different things depending on users clicking and code-behind changing.

Comment: i understand that is what the OP wants; i do not understand why, and suspect a design error in the need

Answer (score 0):

One (hackish) way to do it would be to subclass `RadioButton` and override the `OnCheckChanged` virtual method, suppressing the event if the `Checked` property has been set programmatically.

However, since radio-buttons belong to a group, the event always fires in pairs (oen for the uncheck, one for the check). You will therefore want to suppress the event for the *entire group* when you choose the selected button programmatically. Here's an example implementation:

```
public class CustomRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    private bool _suppressCheckedEvent;

    public void SetChecked(bool value, bool suppressCheckedEvent)
    {
        if (!suppressCheckedEvent)
            Checked = value;
        else
        {
            SetSupressModeForGroup(true);
            Checked = value;
            SetSupressModeForGroup(false);
        }
    }

    private void SetSupressModeForGroup(bool suppressCheckedEvent)
    {
        foreach (var crb in Parent.Controls.OfType<CustomRadioButton>())
            crb._suppressCheckedEvent = suppressCheckedEvent;
    }

    protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suppressCheckedEvent)
            base.OnCheckedChanged(e);
    }   
}
```

In this implementation, changing the checked-state through the `Checked` property will always fire the event. When you call the `SetChecked` method, you have the choice to suppress the event.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to attach the event programmatically. Based on my application configuration I check several radio buttons but I don't want to fire events. 
To attach an event programmatically:

chbOptionX.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.chbShowStockBySizeAndColor_CheckedChanged);

Comment: But still you could _not distinguish_ between setter- and clicking- induced changes when the event fires.